# How to show error message on rails views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, view

I am newbie in `rails` and want to apply validation on `form` fields.

myviewsnew.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :simulation, url: simulations_path do |f|  %>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :Row %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <%= f.text_field :row, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
.....
```

Simulation.rb

```
class Simulation < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 validates :row, :inclusion => { :in => 1..25, :message => 'The row must be between 1 and 25' }
end
```

simulation_controller.rb

```
class SimulationsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @simulations = Simulation.all
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @simulation = Simulation.new(simulation_params)
    @simulation.save
    redirect_to @simulation
  end

  private
   def simulation_params
   params.require(:simulation).permit(:row)
  end
```

I want to check the integer range of `row` field in model class and return the error message if it's not in the range. I can check the range from above code but not able to return the error message

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of   ...Done.

Comment: @NullSoulException I am doing the same thing. I want to show the error message in form

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The key is that you are using a model form, a form that displays the attributes for an instance of an ActiveRecord model. The [create action of the controller](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create) will take care of some validation (and you can [add more validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)).

## Controller re-renders `new` View when model fails to save

Change your controller like below:

```
def new
  @simulation = Simulation.new
end

def create
  @simulation = Simulation.new(simulation_params)
  if @simulation.save
    redirect_to action: 'index'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

When the model instance fails to save (`@simulation.save` returns `false`), then the `new` view is re-rendered.

### `new` View displays error messages from the model that failed to save

Then within your `new` view, if there exists an error, you can print them all like below.

```
<%= form_for @simulation, as: :simulation, url: simulations_path do |f|  %>
  <% if @simulation.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
    <% @simulation.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :Row %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <%= f.text_field :row, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The important part here is that you're checking whether the model instance has any errors and then printing them out:

```
<% if @simulation.errors.any? %>
  <%= @simulation.errors.full_messages %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this -

```
 <%= form_for :simulation, url: simulations_path do |f|  %>
    <% if f.object.errors.any? %>
      <ul>
        <% if f.object.errors.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>

   ..........
 <% end %>
```

Comment: You have an extra if here:  `<% if f.object.errors.each do |message| %>` Tried to edit but it's less than 6 characters so I it would not let me do it.

Answer (score -2):

You just need to add this code to the view file (`myviewsnew.html.erb`):

```
<%= error_messages_for :simulation %>
```

Check complete syntax of `error_messages_for` in http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/ActiveRecordHelper/error_messages_for