# To maintain data in a form after doing a validation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I am validating my form but sending the error message cleans the fields and I want the data to be kept so that I only complete the ones I need

I have this code in the controller:

```
def create
mensaje=""
@farm = Farm.new(params[:farm])
if @farm.nombre==""  || !valid_prescence?(@farm.nombre)
  mensaje="Favor de capturar los datos que se encuentran como requeridos"
else
  @buscar=Farm.where(nombre: params[:farm][:nombre], tipo: params[:farm][:cliente_id])
  if @buscar.any?
    mensaje="La finca "+params[:farm][:nombre]+" ya se encuentra registrada en el sistema, favor de verificar."
  end
end

respond_to do |format|
  if mensaje !=""
    format.html { redirect_to new_farm_path, notice: mensaje }
    format.json { render json: @farm.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  else
    if@farm.save
    format.html { redirect_to @farm, notice: 'Finca creada correctamente.' }
    format.json { render json: @farm, status: :created, location: @farm }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @farm.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end end end
```

At the moment of falling in the exception returns me to the form but with empty fields
What I want is to be able to keep the data after sending the message

[This is part of the form after the validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJv8J.png)

Comment: What does the form look like?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916995/keep-form-fields-filled-after-an-error-ror

Comment: @Rakesh 
It works, but it does not show me the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you put something into `mensaje` the repond will do a redirect to the`new` action, which is why the form is empty. You have to clear out the controller, those validations do not belong there, I've only done some of that work for you.

```
def create
  @farm = Farm.new(params[:farm])
  if @farm.nombre == ""  || !valid_prescence?(@farm.nombre)
    flash[:notice] = "Favor de capturar los datos que se encuentran como requeridos"
  else
    @buscar = Farm.where(nombre: params[:farm][:nombre], tipo: params[:farm][:cliente_id])
    if @buscar.any?
      flash[:notice] = "La finca #{params[:farm][:nombre]} ya se encuentra registrada en el sistema, favor de verificar."
    end
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @farm.save
      format.html { redirect_to @farm, notice: 'Finca creada correctamente.' }
      format.json { render json: @farm, status: :created, location: @farm }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @farm.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

to show error on form have a look at [How to show error message on rails views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092846/how-to-show-error-message-on-rails-views) or http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

Validations don't belong in the controller. Put your validations in the model (business logic). Here is an excellent guide on validations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html.

After that, your controller will reduce and only decide on `if @farm.save` (as https://stackoverflow.com/users/336392/thomas-r-koll already showed).

```
def create
  @farm = Farm.new(params[:farm])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @farm.save
      format.html { redirect_to @farm, notice: 'Finca creada correctamente.' }
      format.json { render json: @farm, status: :created, location: @farm }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @farm.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

It would also be interesting to see your form code in the view. You should be aware that all values as well as the error messages from the validations are inside your @farm instance variable. If you write the form correctly (i.e. following standard Rails conventions), it will automatically display errors and old values.