# ActiveRecord validations + a DRY way to display errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, activerecord

I'd like to catch and display validation errors for ActiveRecord resources attached to an object (here: *:album_artwork*).

I'm following Amit Suroliya suggestion for displaying errors within forms (*f.object.errors* ..., found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092846/how-to-show-error-message-on-rails-views)). Following [guides.rubyonrails.com guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views) (*<% if @article.errors.any? %>*) leads to having errors when the form first loads (before user submit it).

**CODE :**

```rb
# album.rb

  has_one_attached :album_artwork

  validates :name,          presence: { message: 'Album should have a title.' }
  validates :release_date,  presence: { message: 'Album should have a release date.' }
  validates :album_artwork, presence: { message: 'Album should have an artwork.' } # not working :(
```

```rb
#albums_controller.rb

def new
  @album = Album.new
  @album.tracks.build # Album has_many Tracks (doesn't matter here)
end


def create
  @album = Album.new(album_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @album.save
      format.html { redirect_to @album, flash: { success: "Album added" } }
      format.json {  }
    else
      format.html { render 'albums/new', flash: { error: "Something wrong happened :(" } }
      format.json {  }
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# albums/new.html.erb

<%= form_for @album, url: {action: 'create'} do |f| %>

  <% if f.object.errors.any? %>
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <h4>Errors :</h4>
      <ul>
        <% f.object.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= render 'albums/form_new', f: f %>

<% end %>
```

There's 3 points where I can't figure out the best (or any) solution:

- How could I validate the *file_field* corresponding to *:album_artwork* ?
- When validations fail, URL points to */albums* instead of */albums/new* (however, */albums/new* is displayed, but I'm redirected to */albums* if I refresh)
- Is there any convenient way to make the code for displaying errors DRY ? (a helper rendering partial ?)

Any helping hands, suggestions or critics would be gratefully received !

Have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 `has_one_attached` enables a method `attached?`. You can define your own validation method, that uses this to perform validation. ActiveStorage (where the `has_one_attached` comes from) does not support validations on its own yet. It will in Rails 6 but I assume you are not using this version of RAILS. You could even move the validations to an outside validator and use that to validate the file presence, size, type etc. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-with
Moving validations from the model is usually considered good practice in the long term.

2 Try to use redirect when there are errors, the same way you do it when form succedes (instead of render).

3 Yes, you can just move the part responsible for displaying errors into a partial that's easy to access across the application, and render it in the form under a condition of having errors (or render it always, but it won't display anything in it if there are no errors)

Also when submitting a question, try to specify what exactly is not working, the way you described validation not working is a bit vague.

Also on a personal note, I suggest using haml instead of erb. But that's only cause you mentioned you wanted some suggestions ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precision, I'll try to be more precise next time. I saw someone using haml in a tutorial, it looks awesome ! (I didnt used it here, it's my first project)

Comment: Sure thing. If you have troubles with the syntax at first, there are erb -> haml converters available online which might prove helpful.

Comment: Thanks again, tbh I can't wait to finish this project and try haml ! If you want to know about the URL problem, if I choose to use *redirect_to* / *redirect_back*, variables won't be passed (so errors won't be displayed). But if I choose *render action: :new*, turbolinks will mess with my URL (https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/60)... Removing turbolinks after implenting AJAX looks the easiest to me, but I'm gonna do it latter (and will read more about that issue)